# Mocking the same function in two different test blocks in Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

I've got a question about creating mocks of functions in Jest. I've got two elements on my page that call different functions in my React component. Both of those functions call the same function, which is passed in from the props, `onFieldChanged`. I want to simulate a change on these two elements, and confirm that `props.onFieldChanged` is called.

When I write the first test (the first test below), it passes with flying colors. When I write the second test, the second test passes but the first test now fails. Basically, I cannot get both tests to pass at the same time. Do I need to reset the mock somehow? Does anyone know how to do this?

What gives?

```
  describe('user selects checkbox', () => {
    props.onFieldChanged = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = shallow(<DateOptions {...props} />);
    it('calls the onFieldChanged function', () => {
      const element = wrapper.find('#addOneToStudyDays');
      element.simulate('change');
      expect(props.onFieldChanged).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });

  describe('user types in input', () => {
    props.onFieldChanged = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = shallow(<DateOptions {...props} />);
    it('calls the onFieldChanged function', () => {
      const element = wrapper.find('#lowerTimeLimit');
      element.simulate('change');
      expect(props.onFieldChanged).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

try to pass jest.fn() as different variable:

```
  describe('user selects checkbox', () => {
    it('calls the onFieldChanged function', () => {
      const onFieldChanged = jest.fn();
      const wrapper = shallow(<DateOptions {...props, onFieldChanged} />);
      const element = wrapper.find('#addOneToStudyDays');
      element.simulate('change');
      expect(props.onFieldChanged).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });

  describe('user types in input', () => {
    it('calls the onFieldChanged function', () => {
      const onFieldChanged = jest.fn();
      const wrapper = shallow(<DateOptions {...props, onFieldChanged} />);
      const element = wrapper.find('#lowerTimeLimit');
      element.simulate('change');
      expect(props.onFieldChanged).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

Comment: @MaxMillington you can always spy on these two instance component methods which are called by lowerTimeLimit and addOneToStudyDays, and then check if these methods call onFieldChanged :)

Comment: I'm trying that now by doing `const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'handleInputFieldChanged');` and then expecting the spy to have been called. `handleInputFieldChanged` is definitely being called (threw some console.logs in there) but it's still saying `Expected mock function to have been called.`

Comment: It's strange that mocked handleInputFieldChanged calls console.log, it should not doing anything after mock.